# Angularjs ng-class not updating when using object annotation style

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I just noticed that something doesn't work in Angular (or it doesn't as I expected it to work) when using object in ng-class.

### What do I expect?

**When changing the name of a property in the object, the class should update accordingly.**

### What did I try?

**I found that when I use object style annotation like 
`ng-class="{obj.prop: testExpression}"` and the `obj.prop` changes (the expression keeping returning TRUE) the value inside ng-class changes but that in the class attribute doesn't.**

---

the difference is between this [NOT WORKING]:

`<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="{ {{user.genre}}: true}">`

and this [WORKING]:

`<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="user.genre">`

---

See a plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/149ba2WQ5RK5XqLmWQWK?p=preview

---

The thing is I need to use object annotation in order to disable the class.

Is there something I am doing wrong or I just misunderstood Angular? 
Or a third solution?

Comment: What class are you trying to add? The value stored in `user.genre`? The syntax you *probably* want is: `ng-class="{ user.genre: true}"`

Comment: Have you tried changing the plunkr? it returns a $parse.syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `{ {{user.genre}}: true}` is not a correct angularjs [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

For your solution, try `ng-class="getClass(user.genre)"`

and do whatever you want in getClass function

[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vHtWXZrnailoKDD8v28O?p=preview)

Comment: that was my previous solution but it still didn't work. I'll create another plunk to test if this works in plunkr -being a much simpler structure than the actual app I'm working on

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do ?

Comment: when changing an object's property -by utterly replacing the object in the array- the class should change. Please inspect the plunkr's tables to see what I mean, while the bottom table has its class changed, the top one doesn't.

Comment: i don't see why you can't use function to do the same thing. http://plnkr.co/edit/vHtWXZrnailoKDD8v28O?p=preview

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it brings to the right path. I was checking for another parameter to be true to enable the class and I was doing it in HTML -which is a bad practise and return non elegant code. Now I've moved all of my logic inside the function. Thanks

Comment: i am facing the same problem, as  my data loads little late in application after some sqllite queries using promise, 
function in ng-class runs before data binds to mark-up .  hence ng-class doesn't update till i invoke some angular event.

though i know if i call ng-class function again in success of data retrieval it will work but i don't want any hack.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to evaluate an object here, hence for each key-value pair of object with a real (truthy) value the corresponding key is used as a class name. If you have single parameter you have to use like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class="user.genre: true">
```

In case of multiple parameter you have to use like:

```
<p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, red: error}">
```

Comment: Are you saying I can't evaluate an object if I want to use multiple parameters?

Comment: I am saying that the object should be in the form of array. Or we have to iterate the object parameters to evaluate.